# Javascript SOAP request with credentials

Tags: soap

I want create a SOAP request in javascript with credentials and without proxy server. Is that possible?

Comment: Does the endpoint you're trying to work with support a JSON or XML API? Either would be much easier to work with than legacy SOAP APIs!

Comment: The endpoint supports XML API

Comment: I'd try working with the XML API instead then.  I haven't used SOAP services in years and would *personally* avoid SOAP wherever possible.